DC LED flickering - connected to Solar Panel (DC) with fan (DC)
I have set up a 100% DC system for my house; solar panel (400 W, 10 A, 40 V) and the circuit connects to two LED fans in series (DC - 12 V) and radiator fan (DC - 24 V).
I'm an arts student and self-taught (e.g. YouTube, friends, etc.) tinkerer in electricity. So, apologies if I made any obvious mistakes.
For several months, the DC system ran smoothly. When the sun rises, it runs as per the irradiance until the sun sets. The LED and fan brightness and speed was in tandem with the irradiance.  The LED did not flicker (but just became brighter and more dim as per the sun).
Recently, the LED light started flickering rapidly. Many times, a second one. It is highly irritating to the eye.  I'm not sure what happened to the LED light.
Can anyone advise what happened?
How can I fix it to stop flickering?

How are you limiting current to the LED?

what kind of a LED light?

the solar panel max-es out at 40v. I run 3 load in series; 2 led (12v) and 1 radiator fan (24v). so very roughly, the max voltage per load is 40v / 3 = 13v.  i heard the actual voltage is actually based on resistance but i don't know how to measure or calculate. since the LED and fan runs on variable voltage, its just a matter of brighter / darker and faster / slower. no problem :)

i purchased the LED light at Shoppee. Its described as 'DC 12V LED T5 Tube Light 10W 2ft 20W 4ft 6500k Daylight'. i'm using the 10w / 2 feet version.  no other details unless i open it up (and probably can't put back afterwards). lol

Depending on the kind of load, it may present a negative (dynamic) resistance to the source. That can cause oscillation. A switching supply generally looks like a negative resistance because the current goes down when the voltage increases.
As to fixing it, you'd probably need a different kind of net load.
